# CloudFormation condition functions value based on parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a `parameter` where I define the environment.

```
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment. Example: qa, prod
    Type: String
```

I'm creating an RDS cluster and, in relation to the environment, I would like to set one or the  other value for `BackupRetentionPeriod`

The logic would be: if is 'prod' the value should be int 35, if not int 7.

```
BackupRetentionPeriod: !Ref Environment = prod, 35, 7
```

I read the documentation, checked several examples but still, I cannot make it work referencing to a parameter, and setting one or other value inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use combination of [If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) and [Equals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-equals) in your CloudFormation:

```
Parameters:

  Environment:
    Description: Environment. Example: qa, prod
    Type: String

Conditions:

  IsProd: 
    !Equals [!Ref Environment, 'prod']  

Resources:

    ....
    ....
    BackupRetentionPeriod: !If [IsProd, 35, 7]
```

You could also make it without separate `Conditions` section, but I think the CFN template is easier to read with it, so I included it.

Comment: I was trying to avoid `Conditions`, thinking that maybe it was possible to perform some conditional logic inline... But, it seems it is not the case. As always, I go with your answer @Marcin - Btw, would you mind to recommend me some resources (links, books) to improve my CFN skills (and Cloud in general). Without commitment :D Again, thanks!

Comment: @Peter Inline should also be possible `!If [ !Equals [!Ref Environment, 'prod'] , 35, 7]`. I think aws docs and their [solutions](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/?solutions-all.sort-by=item.additionalFields.sortDate&solutions-all.sort-order=desc) are good examples for templates. And practice obviously :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you for some reason don't like conditions, you can achieve this with [Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html).
Something along the lines:

```
Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Description: >-
      Type of the environment (eu, tu, au, pu). 

      Please use the same environment for all components/stacks of your
      environment.
    Type: String
    Default: eu
    AllowedValues:
      - eu
      - tu
      - au
      - pu
Mappings:
  BackupRetentionPeriod:
    default:
      pu: 35
      eu: 7
      tu: 7
      au: 7
```

And then:

```
BackupRetentionPeriod: !FindInMap 
  - BackupRetentionPeriod
  - default
  - !Ref EnvType
```